# Application Layer security vs Transport layer security

Tags: tls, appsec

Application layer security or transport layer security which one is better?
TLS is convenient but application layer security will help to provide more security as this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104346/do-we-still-need-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-application-layer-despite-using-tls) explains

Comment: "Better" for what? To secure against what? As asked, this is unanswerable. And do, that other post does not explain that application layer security adds more security. It adds a layer of security to protect against different threats. And it basically answers what you have asked here.